# Cannot use Mongoskin twice in same web request (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mongoskin

For some reason I cannot query MongoDB multiple times during a web request in node.js. VERIFY BY USERNAME and VERIFY BY EMAIL both work perfectly fine on their own, but not in succession. If I comment out either one of the sections of code, the function works as desired. If I leave both sections in, I get a 502 Proxy Error when trying run the request on my Openshift server. I actually always get 502s when I put multiple Mongo queries into a single request (not just on verification). Is there any way I can fix this? Should I be using some sort of async call?

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  userVerify(req, res);
  //VERIFY BY USERNAME
  db.collection('userlist').findOne({'username': req.body.username}, function (err, item){
      if(item.username == req.body.username)
      {
        if(passwordGen.verify(req.body.password, item.password)==true)
        {
          //res.render('logged_in.html', {});
          res.send( {msg: 'success'} )
        }
      }
    });
  //VERIFY BY EMAIL    
  db.collection('userlist').findOne({'email': req.body.username}, function (err, item){
    if(item.email == req.body.username)
    {
      if(passwordGen.verify(req.body.password, item.password)==true)
      {
        res.send( {msg: 'success'} );
      }
    }
  });
  //Return an error if the both failed.
  res.send( {msg: 'ERROR'} );
});
```

Comment: These to do execute in succession as you might think. You likely need to nest one within the callback of the other, but the intention of what you are trying to achieve here is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is important because it is showing a very basic aspect of using MongoDB under Node.

You already got the answer as a comment of @Neil. Each of these operations is asynchronous and should not run them in parallel. Your current code is showing a race between two threads querying the DB, the first to come back, the first to call res.send() and finish the response.

So what you had to do is nest them one inside the other: wait for DB response to verify the password, then start verifying the email, and when done - respond to the caller

HTH